# using jquery to get the 'src' of an image link?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say i have the following:

```
<a class="class1"><img src=".." /></a>
```

If I am currently in the click event of a.class1, how to I pull the 'src' value of the 'img'?

**Update:** for some reason neither of the suggestions below worked. My code looks like this:

```
 $("a.class1").click( function() {
     alert($(this).children('img').attr('src'));
 });
```

This pops up 'undefined' (for both suggestions).  Why is this happening?

Comment: The code above is working fine for me.
alert($(this).children('img').attr('src')); just shows the value present in src="" in img tag.

Comment: is that the exact html you're using?

Comment: well..the img src is actually being populated by another jquery 'hover' event to achieve a rollover effect...but should this affect the outcome?

Comment: Maybe. Could you pls try to post the events related to the image. so that it would be easy for us to figure out the issue.

Comment: Yeah, if there are other events going on affecting things, 'this' could be losing its' scope. Can you post your code, or a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("img", this).attr("src")
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
$(this).children('img').attr('src')
```